# Java private member: why does this compile?

Tags: java

Why is this compiling?

`a` is private... how come I can call `c2.a`?

I am confused.

Thank for your help!

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int a;
    public double b;

    public MyClass(int first, double second)
    {
    this.a = first;
    this.b = second;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    MyClass c1 = new MyClass(10, 20.5);
    MyClass c2 = new MyClass(10, 31.5);
    System.out.println(c2.a + ", "+ c2.b);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Because you're accessing it from inside MyClass...?  Why would you expect this to *not* compile?

Comment: `private` wouldn't be any good if **noone** could access it :)